# Hibernate select manyToMany association with a criteria containing all the elements of a list

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have two Hibernate Entities A and B.
There is a ManyToMany association between A and B.

```java
public class A {
  @ManyToMany(targetEntity=B.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "AB",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="A_FK"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="B_FK"))  
  private Set<B> collectionOfB = new HashSet<B>();
  // ...
}

public class B {
  // no reference to A
}
```

I have an array {b1, b2,... ,bn} of B elements.

I need to search all the A elements that are associated to ALL the B elements of the list above (all the elements of {b1, b2,... ,bn} should be in collectionOfB).

So I have to do something like this:

```
select * from A as a where {b1, b2,... ,bn} in a.collectionOfB
```

But this is not possible :-(

Does anybody have an idea how to deal with this ?

Thanks

Kamran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found out that the easiest way to deal with my problem was to use native SQL through `session.createSQLQuery(sql)`.

With:

```
sql="select a.* from A a where ...";
for (Long bId: myListOfBcriteria) {
  sql += " and " + bId+ " in (select ab.b_fk from AB ab where ab.a_fk=a.id)";
}
```

where `myListOfBcriteria={b1, b2,... ,bn}`.

Perhaps it's not very 'nice' but it works well :-)

I hope this can help some one,

Kamran

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your new content. Perhaps you should edit your question also. It is the Stackoverflow way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

If your mappings are correct you can do this:

```
    sql="select a.* from A a where ...";
    for (Long bId: myListOfBcriteria) {
        sql += " and " + bId+ " in (select ab.b_fk from AB ab where ab.a_fk=a.id)";
    }
```

in Hibernate.

```
    select a from A join a.collectionOfB as ab where ab.id in (:collectionOfB)
```

If you are going to use ORM you should use it unless you absolutely cannot.

Comment: Dear Carbontax, Thanks, for your answer. No I need that all the elements of my query collection are in a.collectionOfB (or a.b in what your wrote)